# Using multiple XY fields for geometry definition in point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, geometry, visualisation, point-creation

In QGIS 3.26.3 Buenos Ares I have a set of drill hole point data with XY fields for the *planned* drill hole location and a second set of fields for the *surveyed* XY location after drilling.

I want to visualise these data using the *surveyed* location as the primary, but in the event that the surveyed data doesn't exist (the hole hasn't been drilled/surveyed yet) i'd like QGIS to read from the *planned* drill hole field. Is this possible to achieve within a single layer? Or do I have to create two layers, one for each criterion?

Comment: I think you vave to use two layers. As I understand your data source is csv or xls file? Then you can recalc source data and reload layer.

Comment: No need for second layer. See solution below

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 11):

Use a Geometry Generator style for your point layer with an expression that creates a point based on x/y coordinate values for surveyed locations if it exists and else create a point based on x/y coordinate values for planned locations.

This expression does this based on field names of coordinate attributes called `x_surveyed`/`y_surveyed` and `x_planned`/`y_planned` respectively:

```
if (
    x_surveyed is not NULL,
    make_point(x_surveyed, y_surveyed),
    make_point(x_planned, y_planned)
)
```

*Screenshot: red = surveyed, blue = planned holes (here with a slightly different expression, using `case...when` condition - it works the same):*
[image]

You could also use two different symbol layers of Geometry Generator type (one for planning, one for surveyed locations) and apply a different style for each. Or use one symbol layer with the solution from above, but define a data-defined override for the color, something like:

```
if(x_surveyed is not NULL, 'red', 'blue')
```

---

References:

- [Use QGIS expressions to create geometries: difference between geometry generator and geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/392618/use-qgis-expressions-to-create-geometries-difference-between-geometry-generator)

Comment: Better to have `x_surveyed is not NULL and y_surveyed is not NULL`

Comment: Why that? This would only make sense if there is a value for y, but not for x. In such a case, no point can be created, so this case can be ignored.

Comment: *Explicit is better than implicit*

Comment: *Short and simple is better than long and complicated* ;-)